# cannot change theme of modelio - GTK_THEME variable doesn't work

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, gtk, gtk3, gnome-tweaks

[image]I use Ubuntu 18.04 and have set my default application theme to adwaita-dark. however Modelio looks awful in this otherwise wondeerful theme - for instance doesn't show a lot of things - as you can see in the screenshot i cant see the project names being displayed on the left panel until i click on them.
I tried shifting dekstop app to .local/share/applications and changed the variable EXEC as -

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita:light /usr/bin/modelio-open-source4.1
```

but it does not change anything - modelio still launches with default application. i also tried -

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita /usr/bin/modelio-open-source4.1
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Ambiance /usr/bin/modelio-open-source4.1
```

none of these work. is there a solution?

Comment: On MATE with [deb-packaged version](https://www.modelio.org/download.html?task=download.send&id=172&catid=37&m=0) I see that ModelIO appearance is changing on theme change without any additional file edits. What is your desktop environment? Can you share a screenshot of ModelIO with non-wonderful appearance?

Comment: okay just added a picture of the issue - i am using default ubuntu 18.04 so using gnome and changed my theme through tweaks!